# Hankel operations

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I've been reading some scientific articles and in some of them terms like "Hankel operator", "Hankel operation", "Hankel matrix" are mentioned. I tried "googling" mentioned terms but some offered search results were a bit too mathematically advanced for me to understand much. I would like to get a short intuitive explanation on a basic level (if possible) of what are Hankel operations and more importantly what are their purposes and why are they important to us. Also, it would be nice if you could suggest some introductory level literature on related topics to get more familiar with this branch of mathematics (functional analysis, I'm assuming ?).

Comment: If you could give more detail on what your background is and in what context you ran into these terms, it'll be easier to give appropriate help.

Comment: I have background in linear algebra, calculus, real analysis, probability theory and differential equations. Nothing too advanced just enough for engineering purposes. I was reading a text related to control theory.